# upgrade amazon ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, wamp

I am wanting to upgrade my t2.micro EC2 windows server. I have read the amazon resize link
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-resize.html
and it asks to "stop" my server. My server is EBS and when i try to stop I get a wrning that says "all ephemeral storage will be deleted". Will my WAMP setup (apache, mysql database, PHP) running on C:\ and all database be lost? How do i make sure it isn't?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can safely upgrade your t2.micro instance from AWS Dashboard.

Simply perform the following steps:

1. stop the instance (since t2.micro is EBS-backed by default, no data will be lost)
2. when the instance is stopped, right-click and select "change instancy type" from dropdown menu.
3. start the image once the instance type is successfully changed

Answer (score 2):

[t2.micro](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/) does not have any ephemeral (instance) storage available with it. You must have explicitly associated an EBS volume with the instance. You can stop the instance - data won't be lost.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by:

**Without Stopping Instance:**

Create a Snapshot of your Volume.
Create Image from Snapshot.
Launch Instance from the AMI and with your desired Instance Type.

It will save all your Configuration and Data.

**With Stopping Instance:**
As you have mentioned all your data is on EBS.
Stop the Instance.
Create an Image of the Instance.
Launch Instance from the AMI and with your desired Instance Type.

It will save all your Configuration and Data.

Hope It Helps.. :)